# Can't access Windows 10 after dual booting it with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

New to askubuntu but not that new to linux.

So I dual booted my Windows 10 with Ubuntu. I installed the .iso with rufus on a pen drive and it created a partition automatically (I decided what space Windows and Ubuntu got by sliding a partition bar). I had some errors where Ubuntu wouldn't boot, fixed it with a command in a terminal and it showed the grub menu and let me choose between OS.

A couple days passed, using Windows and Ubuntu, but now when I choose Windows it won't boot. The Acer logo comes on and displays "Diagnosing your PC", goes dark, then the logo comes up again and shows "Initiation automatic repairs" and stays there. Meanwhile, I can freely use Ubuntu and access my Windows files.

I don't know what has gone wrong, I tried using Boot Repair to fix this problem. It only showed more options to choose from in the grub menu, but even trying those the same thing happens.

I would appreciate the help. Thanks fellow forum users.

Comment: You are supposed to shrink your windows partition from within windows. Not outside it using gparted.

Comment: When I installed ubuntu i boote the pc with the usb drive, ubuntu installer shows up and ask me where to install it. I shrank my windows. If that was gparted, then damn stupid me haha. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Sorry I don't know.